# Doubt in Carathéodory's extension theorem

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, extension-field

I am new to the field of measure theory so I apologize before hand if this question is too trivial. It is stated that if $\Sigma_{0}$ is an algebra on set $S$ and $\mu_{0}$ is a positive measure/finitely additive map on $\Sigma_{0}$ . Let $\Sigma=\sigma(\Sigma_0)$, then there is a measure $\mu$ on $(S,\Sigma)$ such that $\mu(F)=\mu_0(F)$, $\forall$ F $\in \Sigma_0$ . I had a doubt like here $\Sigma$ is a $\sigma-$algbra on $S$ and that means it is closed under countable union and set complementation. So there must be infinite collection of subsets that belongs to $\Sigma$. But algebra $\Sigma_0$ is closed under finite intersection . The intuition is not clear since how can one extend a measure on finite collection (i.e. algebra) of subsets to a measure of infinite collection of subsets (i.e. in $\sigma-$algebra) ? It is very much intuitive that a property working on a subset of a set may not be true for the entire set. So how do one provides explanation for this ?

Comment: Did you remember the theorem correctly? I think $\mu_0$ should be $\sigma$-additive.

Comment: You mean to say countably additive ? But how is that possible for the case when we define an algebra of a set where it is closed under finite union ? I mean how we can consider it to be countably additive in this case ?

Comment: An algebra $\Sigma_0$ means you cannot expect, for example, the union of countable many sets in $\Sigma_0$ to be in $\Sigma_0$ again. However, if it does lie in $\Sigma_0$ (this is possible, just note that $\cup[n,n+1)=\mathbb{R}$, where $\Sigma_0$ is taken as the algebra generated by $[n,n+1)$), then $\mu_0$ should satisfy a countable additive property for this set (in the above example, $\Sigma\mu_0([n,n+1))=\mu_0(\mathbb{R})$).

Comment: So that means the extension theorem is true (and holds a unique extension) iff the measure defined on the algebra on a given set satisfies countably additive property as well as the algebra itself is closed under countable union ?

Comment: The measure(this terminology is not proper used here, by the way) should be countable additive, while the algebra need not be closed under countable union.

Comment: So that clears my doubt. If it was restricted to being additive then an extension would'nt have been possible. Thanks a lot. Which book to follow to get a more clear intuition on measure theory ?

Comment: A standard real analysis textbook is recommended. There is just a long list of them from which you can choose. But since you're trying to learn probability theory, I think Probability Theory by A.Klenke(http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-84800-048-3)  may be nice.